# R shiny- print function output (message) to ui

Tags: r, shiny

Let's say there is a function like this, printing some message when running:

```
 queryMagic <- function() {
    print("Warning")

    return("Data")
  }
```

How can I run the function only once to get both the result as a reactive and also render the "warning" to the ui?
Many thanks!!

Comment: "Warning" will display on R's console. Do you want to see it inside the app? As a pop-up message or inside an output?

Comment: I would need to see it in the app, as an output.